# Binding margins getting scrambled when using setcounter

Tags: margins, page-numbering

I'm writing a thesis and I need to have 4cm inner and 2cm outer margins.
I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
```

It does seem to have asymmetric margins, however they are not correctly maintained throughout the document. I can only assume because I have a number of `setcounter` statements.

For example, the title page has no page number.

The next page is the abstract, and I use

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
```

Then I have the acknowledgments, dedication, etc, and they have similar roman numbering that I have defined.

Then I have

```
\newpage
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
```

and then for the introduction

```
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
```

then the literature review

```
\newpage
\chapter{Literature Review}
\setcounter{mtc}{2}
\minitoc
```

and it goes on from there with no more `setcounter` statements.

I don't remember why I needed that `setcounter{mtc}{2}` but it's there so it does something. So basically I'm using this so I can have roman numbering before the introduction and then arabic numbering for the introduction onwards, and the first page of the introduction should start at page 1.

I think the odd and even pages are getting confused because I'm changing the page counter. Is there any way to fix this? Maybe decouple what's on the bottom of the page and instead use the page number from the generated PDF?

Thanks.

Comment: Other counters should have no influence. But you have to be careful with the page counter. The left/right page layout is based on the page counter, so if you have to even numbers following each other, or two odd ones then you get into trouble because then the left/right gets reversed when printing. So make sure that you only change the page counter after a `\newpage`, `\clearpage`, or `\cleardoublepage`. Best is to issue first `\cleardoublepage`, and then change the page number, but the new number must be odd (usually 1).

Comment: Is there any news here? I have seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356923/multi-page-list-of-figures-tables-with-odd-even-margins# and this seems to be of the same nature.